# Can the ratio of gravitational force to Coulomb repulsion force in the nucleus be increased by adding neutrons? How many?

Tags: nuclear-physics, coulombs-law, binding-energy, strong-force, isotopes

As you know, the ratio of gravitational force to Coulomb repulsion force between two protons is very small. This means that the source of nuclear stability cannot be the force of gravity. Can some neutrons be added to increase this ratio? If yes, how many?

Comment: Have you heard of the strong force?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction

Comment: anna v       Yes, I know that the main source of nuclear stability is strong force. But my question is assuming that we do not know about strong force and we want to know if we can increase this ratio by adding neutrons or not? If yes, how many? If not, why not?

Comment: look at the stability line here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability . Complex quantum mechanical models are used to explain it, and they only consider the strong and the Coulomb force. Gravity is thirty five orders of magnitude smaller at the quantum level from the coulomb force, it is nonexistent at the nuclear level.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html

Answer (score 0):

The number of neutrons that can be added to a nucleus is not dependent on the gravitational force but instead on the Nuclear or strong force. Netrons are added to increase the nuclear force to offset the coulomb repulsion of the protons. You can make a guess by looking at Uranium - 238. Uranium has 92 protons and 146 neutrons or a 54 neutron excess. Once more neutrons are added, the nucleus Uranium = 239 is unstable and adding more neutrons produces shorter half-life isotopes as the uranium nucleus becomes less stable. [It has been reported](https://nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html) that uranium-243 has been produced but with a very short half-life. This isotope is not naturally occuring.

If you consider the partially successful shell model of the nucleus then you can start to understand this maximum number of neutrons. As neutrons are added they must go into a shell with a vacancy. These shells are higher and higher in energy as you add more neutrons. They become less bound as the neutrons move further away from the center of the nucleus. At some point the neutron shell becomes unbound and needs another proton to add some more nuclear force in the lower shells of the protons..